# Scala Swing reactions in an extended Panel

Tags: events, swing, scala

Well, simple question: I have a singleton object that extends `scala.swing.Panel`, and I want to have it react on a simple mouse click. But... well, it doesn't work. Since Scala's such a new language, finding infos to specific problems is not so easy. Maybe you can help:

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._
import java.awt.{Graphics2D, Color}

object GamePanel extends Panel {
  val map: TileMap = new TileMap(10, 10)({
    (x, y) =>
      if (x == y) new Wood
      else if (x == 5) new Water
      else new Grass
  })

  reactions += {
    case MouseClicked(src, pt, mod, clicks, pops) => {
      selectedTile = (pt.x / map.tw, pt.y / map.th)
      println("Clicked")
      repaint
    }
  }

  var selectedTile = (0, 0)

  override def paint(g: Graphics2D) = {
    map.draw(g)
    g.setColor(Color.red)
    g.drawRect(selectedTile._1 - 1, selectedTile._2 - 1, 33, 33)
  }
}
```

Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mouse events are not handled by default in Scala Swing for performance reasons.
In your case you need to add a

```
listenTo(mouse.clicks)
```

to your `object` but there is also an event publisher `mouse.moves` you can listen to if you need to track the mouse move events.